# ADD_DATE if Date expired (automatic subscription)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to calculate via MariaDB query a date of recurring subscription based on this information:
For Example:
start_date:01.01.2019
period_of_validity: 4 (Months)
regular_finish_date:01.05.2019, 01.09.2019, 01.01.2020, "01.05.2020"
finished_by_user_at:
membership_will_finished_at:
Case1:
When finished_by_user_at is NULL (It means, the user doesnt cancel his subscription) the regular_finish_date should be update automatically after the interval was reached. As we can see in the example above, the date it should show now is 01.05.2020.
Wo can help me with this Task? No php, java or something else is possible. Only MYSQL query. Thanks

```
SELECT
subscription.SubscriptionID,
subscription.tb_usersID,
subscription.subscription_planID,
subscription.payment_typeID,
subscription.start_date,
DATE_ADD(subscription.start_date, INTERVAL subscription_plan.period_of_validity MONTH) AS date_joker,
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL subscription_plan.period_of_validity MONTH) AS regular_finish_date,
subscription.finished_by_user_at,
(CASE
WHEN subscription.finished_by_user_at IS NOT NULL THEN
(CASE
WHEN subscription.regular_finish_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL subscription_plan.period_of_validity MONTH THEN
DATE_ADD(subscription.regular_finish_date, INTERVAL subscription_plan.period_of_validity MONTH)
END)
END) AS membership_will_finished_at,
subscription.is_active,
subscription.status,
subscription.notizen,
subscription.file1,
subscription.file2,
subscription.file3
FROM subscription
JOIN subscription_plan ON subscription.subscription_planID = subscription_plan.subscription_planID
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not store dates in this format:  `01.01.2019`.  Instead, use `2019-01-01`.  And store them with datatype `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`.  *Then* you can use date expressions.

Suggested indexes:

```
subscription_plan:  (subscription_planID, period_of_validity)
subscription:  (subscription_planID)
```